# Modelling the unsaturated zone in FeFlow in seawater intrusion scenarios

Tags: hydrology, groundwater

Does anyone have experience with modelling seawater intrusion scenarios in Feflow?

In my models, my mass-concentration seems to drive up into the unsaturated vadose zone, which I don't believe is correct.

I'm using Feflow v7.1 with Richards unsaturated flow equations.